# C# Remove Unwanted GUI Method in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

New to Visual Studio C# forms...

Unwanted GUI Methods for group box and labels:

```
    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void folderPathLabel_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void destinationPathLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Error Code when I delete methods:

`Error 1   'A_Better_Backer.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'groupBox1_Enter' and no extension method 'groupBox1_Enter'`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the control with the error (in your case groupBox1) and remove the OnEnter event handler. You can right-click on the control and select Properties, then click on the events icon in the properties window (looks like a lightning) and then delete the unused event handler.

Comment: ideally you should not edit that file by hand since it is generated by the IDE and you can mess it up... but if you are careful I guess it is alright...

Answer (score 1):

When adding such events, besides adding the method in the question, Visual Studio IDE automatically adds registration to the appropriate events of those methods (such as `GroupBox.Enter`, `Label.Click`) to the Designer code. You have to delete this registration code also.